# Performance impact of getter in template in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am taking over an existing Angular app. In it, I keep seeing values used in the templates in many component is actually a property masked with getters/setters, without any additional logic :

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="age" [disabled]="formDisabled">


get formDisabled() {
    return this._formDisabled;
}
set formDisabled(value: boolean) {
    this._formDisabled = value;
}
```

Our app has performance objectives. In AngularJS, any functions in template had a performance impact, because it had to be computed (even just to return value). Is it still truth in Angular (now 5) and should I replace those useless accessors with the direct field if I come across them ?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you mentioned you are taking over an existing app, are you in a team of developers? If you are, you should ask your team as it may/could be decision made among your team to do it that way to keep the code consistence. Otherwise if you're not in a team and you see no value in it, remove it.

Comment: It is a very small team (2 ppl) ; original developpers have left. We are  taking over and we wanted both to know if there was impact from those getters or if we can afford to let that untouched.

Comment: From what I know, there is performance impact. I only use getter/setter if there's any logic in them or for `BehaviourSubject`

Answer (score -3):

Yes, I believe so, functions will be called each change detection cycle.

However, a getter is better, without even better.

Reference (part 3):
https://netbasal.com/optimizing-the-performance-of-your-angular-application-f222f1c16354